# Is the set of Natural Numbers an Algebraic Set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Is the set of natural numbers considered as a subset of $\mathbb A^2$ an affine algebraic set? (ie, zero set of an ideal in $k[x_1,x_2]$)

Comment: No, it is not even a semi-algebraic set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_algebraic_geometry  The logical theory of the reals is **much easier** than the logical theory of the natural numbers.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-minimal_theory

Answer (score 1):

No. If a polynomial $f \in k[x_1 , x_2]$ annihilates the points $(n,0)$ where $n$ is a natural number, then $f(x,0)$ is zero at infinitely many points, and hence $f(x,0) = 0$, i.e. $f$ annihilates the whole $x$-axis. So this set in question can not be defined by polynomials, since the whole $x$-axis will always come with it "for free".

Comment: how can we say I is generated by only one polynomial? There could be m many right?

Comment: Well, you need to write clearer - what is $I$? But assume I understood. We just saw that probably the $x$-axis is the Zariski closure of your set, so $I$ is the set of ideals annihilating the $x$-axis. It is not hard to imagine that $I$ is generated by the polynomial $y$. So a new exercise will be - if a polynomial $f \in k[x,y]$ annihilates the $x$-axis, then $f$ is divisible by $y$.

Comment: oh I see. Any element in I will give me the x axis for "free". Thanks anyway.